# Node JS and express public folder 404 error it looks at the wrong file name

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I have a GET function to display a specific post by a specific user

The code:

```
router.get('/post/:id', isLoggedIn, async(req, res) => {
 Post.findOne({"_id": ObjectID(req.params.id)}, (err, posts) => {
    res.render('post', {post:post,
      user: req.user, isLoggedIn: req.isLogged,
    });
  })

  if(req.query.search) {
    const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.search), 'gi');
    const allPosts = await Post.find({title: regex})

    res.render('generalfeed', {
      user: req.user, isLoggedIn: req.isLogged,
      posts: allPosts
    });
  }

  else{  
    res.render('post', {
      user: req.user, isLoggedIn: req.isLogged
    });
  }

  
});
```

This is what called that GET function:

```
<a href="post/<%= post._id%>"  class="post_link">View Article</a>
```

and this is my Node.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// const Post = require('./models/post');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const path = require('path');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');

const app = express();

require('./config/passport')(passport);

// mongoDB
const dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/the-little-helper';

mongoose.connect(dbURI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then((result) => app.listen(3000), console.log("Connection success!"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/venobox'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/webfonts'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.path = req.path;
  next();
});

app.use(session({
      secret: 'secret',
      resave: true,
      saveUninitialized: true
    })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use('/', require('./routes/router'));
```

IT GETS:
GET /post/css/index_css.css 404 1.046 ms - 161

INSTEAD OF:
GET /public/css/index_css.css

This is how index_css.css is called in the post.ejs:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index_css.css">
```

Thank you!

Comment: Add **/** in front of `css/index_css.css`.

Comment: @Max thank you so much guys I tried this one awhile ago it didn't work but somehow it worked this time!!!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you!!!